# tabularx works on its own but not as a new environment

Tags: environments, tabularx

I am creating a new environment. At the moment it uses `tabular` and I want to port it to `tabularx`.

An isolated `tabularx` table works, but the same table used as an environment fails to compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{asidex}%
{%
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{|l|}
}%
{%
    \end{tabularx}%
}

\newenvironment{aside}%
{%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|}
}%
{%
    \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{aside}  % <------------------------ change this to asidex
    xxx
\end{aside}    % <------------------------ change this to asidex

\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{|l|} % <-- this plain table works
foo
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

In the above, `aside` works, but if you change the envionment to use `asidex`, it fails to compile with

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.27 \end{tabularx}
```

What's odd is that the `begin...end` seems like it should be reproducing the "plain table" at the bottom. The plain table compiles, but the same table when produced for the `asidex` environment doesn't.

What's happening here?

Comment: that is documented feature in the package documentation. see `texdoc tabularx` page 4

Comment: I think we have different ideas of what "clearly" means. I think I found what you're referring to, but *unless you already have a lot of experience*, it's not at all obvious. You've been very helpful to me, but please remember that Q&A sites are for people who *don't* already know what they're looking for.

Comment: No problem! The comment told you what you should do; a search done knowing what to look for pointed to a duplicate. The important thing is that your problem is solved, isn't it?

Comment: Perhaps I was in an odd mood, but I took the tone badly in your original woring. Apologies if that was misplaced, @DavidCarlisle , I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @spraff yes sorry about that first version of the comment didn't come out quite as I intended, I did edit it a bit but had to dash out, anyway hope you found the declaration needed.